# How can I use &str or an enum as field type?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

<Hi I have Postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  age INT NOT NULL,
  sex CHAR(1)
);
```

Where sex can be char 'M' or 'F' or null. Unfortunately, migration sex column to postgres enum is not possible in this case.

I am using rust sqlx to load data from this table. I have:

```
#[derive(sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct PersonSql {
  pub age: int,
  pub sex: Option<String>, // TODO improve it
}
```

Everything works perfectly, but I am afraid that using String type is not the most efficient. It would be nice to `Option<char>`, enum `Option<Sex>`, or at least `Option<&str>`, I tried to use enum like:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, sqlx::Type, Debug)]
#[sqlx(type_name = "VARCHAR")]
pub enum Sex {
  F,
  M,
}
```

compilation is ok, but error is returned when I run app:

> mismatched types; Rust type `core::option::Option<app::Sex>`
> (as SQL type `VARCHAR`) is not compatible with SQL type `CHAR`',

Comment: you can create an enum: https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/types/trait.Type.html#enumeration

Comment: I tried, but i returns error:  mismatched types; Rust type core::option::Option<app::Sex> (as SQL type VARCHAR) is not compatible with SQL type CHAR',